# Why can't I set the FROM name correctly using Gmail in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail

I am trying to get the emails I send through Gmail from my Ruby on Rails app to be from `Ben`.

Currently when the email arrives in a (seperate, non-related) Gmail account, in the Inbox it has `ben` in the from section.

Here are my settings:

setup_mail.rb

```
# my domain is my_example.com, and the email address I am sending from is ben@my_example.com
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "my_example.com",
  :user_name            => "ben@my_example.com",
  :password             => "my_password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
if Rails.env.development?
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000" 
else    
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "my_example.com"
end
```

report_mailer.rb

```
  def send_notification_email(notification_details)
    subject = "testing_email"
    mail(:to => notification_details[:email], :subject => subject, :from => "Ben")  
  end
```

And here are the email settings in Gmail:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the :from part you can actually specify the email address this way :

```
:from => 'Ben <ben@my_example.com>'
```

Comment: If you are using devise, then you can set the from field in your `config/initializers/devise.rb` with the following: `config.mailer_sender = "\"Awesome Name\" <awesome_name@#{Rails.application.secrets.domain_name}>"`

Answer (score 2):

The `:from` key there is actually the email you're sending it from. GMail does not allow this to be overriden, as it can lead to abuse.

Comment: But where is it getting the 'ben' part? That is what appears in the from section in a Gmail inbox (I have edited this into the question).

Comment: From your Gmail account, go to Settings -> Accounts. There is a field Send email as: Most likely it's set to Ben there

Comment: I think that's what the screenshot I included was? Is there another area?